# ocaml hello world make not working

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml

So I just installed ocaml on my ubuntu (12.04). By default it installs 3.12.1. I wrote the following hello word program in `hello.ml`

```
print_string "Hello alok\n";;
```

but when I try to compile and run `hello.ml`, it just doesn't print anything. I am running these commands to compile hello.ml

```
ocamlc -o hello hello.ml
./hello
```

I am starting my terminal, going to the directory where `hello.ml` is, starting ocaml and giving the above command but it does nothing.

If I manually try to print `hello world` by writing `print_string "Hello alok\n";;` on the ocaml window itself, it works fine.

Please help me regarding this!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it works on OS X:

```
$ cat alok.ml
print_string "Hello alok\n"
```

(So, I have a file named alok.ml with your program text in it.)

```
$ ocamlc -o alok alok.ml
$ ./alok
Hello alok
```

This just shows that it works on OS X as expected, and so it should work on Ubuntu also. The commands you give look a little garbled, though maybe it's just the formatting. Your description of what you tried is also a little confusing--you certainly don't want to do the compiling from *inside* the OCaml top-level.

I hope this helps. If not, maybe you could show an actual session on ubuntu. I.e., show exactly what you typed and what the output looks like.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, it is exactly what you said. I was doing this stupid little mistake, was compiling from inside the ocaml.. ahh felt so embarrassing afterwords :D

Answer (score 0):

`print_string` does not automatically flush the content of the standard output, so you need to flush it yourself.

In you example, you can replace it by:

```
print_string "Hello alok\n";;
flush stdout;;
```

Alternatively, you can also use `print_endline`:

```
print_endline "Hello alok";;
```

or the `print_newline` function:

```
print_string "Hello alok";;
print_newline ();;
```